# Run an async loop indefinitely from button click from Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, asynchronous, xamarin

What is the best way to run a loop infinitely in parallel with the application?

This is what I have tried so far:

The button that actives the loop:

```
private void ActiveDeactiveTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    active = !active;            
}
```

The loop:

```
bool runTest = false;
bool active = false;
public async void Test()
{
    while (runTest)
    {
       if (active)
       {
           LblOutput.Text = "before";
           await Task.Delay(1000);
           LblOutput.Text = "after";
        }
        else
        {
           LblOutput.Text = "Idle";
        }
    }
}
```

And the form instantiation:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    runTest = true;
    Test();
}
```

Fairly new to this so any help would be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Comment: you should run this on a separate thread, not the UI thread

Comment: @Jason Sure but I cannot access 'Thread thread = new Thread(function);' in Xamarin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is the best way to loop infinitely but I will provide some of the options. Idea is to start another thread from your main application thread and leverage the loops, usually while, to manage indefinite looping.

Be careful if you are developing UI application because they are quite sensitive in terms of background work. For example, WPF allow only access to UI elements only to the thread which create them, thread known as Dispatcher. This mean that every background thread which need to update UI elements needs to delegate work to dispatcher thread. This is also the case with android with the difference that Dispatcher thread is called UI thread ([WPF Dispatcher Thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx), [Android UI Thread](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html))

**WPF**

> In WPF, a DispatcherObject can only be accessed by the Dispatcher it is associated with.  For example, a background thread cannot update the contents of a Button that is associated with the Dispatcher on the UI thread. In order for the background thread to access the Content property of the Button, the background thread must delegate the work to the Dispatcher associated with the UI thread. This is accomplished by using either Invoke or BeginInvoke. Invoke is synchronous and BeginInvoke is asynchronous. The operation is added to the queue of the Dispatcher at the specified DispatcherPriority.

**Android**

> The Android UI toolkit is not thread-safe. So, you must not manipulate your UI from a worker thread—you must do all manipulation to your user interface from the UI thread. Thus, there are simply two rules to Android's single thread model:
>
> 1. Do not block the UI thread
> 2. Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread

I will provide few examples just as a show case:

```
//Option A, common one, loop doesn't need to have iteration at all
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{               
    while (shouldLooping)
    {
        //do your job
    }
});

//Option B, kind of wierd, loop will have at least one iteration
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{               
    do
    {
        //do your job
    } while (shouldLooping);
});

//Option C, if you are driven by producer/consumer pattern, BlockingCollection should be shared between producer and consumer
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    foreach (var item in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
});
```